# How to create programatic bookmark into browser using Android sdk?

Tags: android, sdk, bookmarks, android-browser

I've seen apps doing this, but I don't have a clue where to start. Any hints? Some code snippets will be appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Create Browser-Bookmark from app](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4589062/create-browser-bookmark-from-app)

Answer (score 2):

```
/**
 * Add a bookmark to the database.
 * 
 * @param context
 *            Context of the calling Activity. This is used to make Toast confirming that the bookmark has been added. If the caller provides null, the Toast will not be shown.
 * @param cr
 *            The ContentResolver being used to add the bookmark to the db.
 * @param url
 *            URL of the website to be bookmarked.
 * @param name
 *            Provided name for the bookmark.
 * @param thumbnail
 *            A thumbnail for the bookmark.
 * @param retainIcon
 *            Whether to retain the page's icon in the icon database. This will usually be <code>true</code> except when bookmarks are added by a settings restore agent.
 */
static void addBookmark(Context context, ContentResolver cr, String url, String name, Bitmap thumbnail, boolean retainIcon) {

    final String WHERE_CLAUSE = "url = ? OR url = ? OR url = ? OR url = ?";
    final String WHERE_CLAUSE_SECURE = "url = ? OR url = ?";
    String[] SELECTION_ARGS;

    // Want to append to the beginning of the list
    long creationTime = new Date().getTime();
    // First we check to see if the user has already visited this
    // site. They may have bookmarked it in a different way from
    // how it's stored in the database, so allow different combos
    // to map to the same url.
    boolean secure = false;
    String compareString = url;
    if (compareString.startsWith("http://")) {
        compareString = compareString.substring(7);
    } else if (compareString.startsWith("https://")) {
        compareString = compareString.substring(8);
        secure = true;
    }
    if (compareString.startsWith("www.")) {
        compareString = compareString.substring(4);
    }
    if (secure) {
        SELECTION_ARGS = new String[2];
        SELECTION_ARGS[0] = "https://" + compareString;
        SELECTION_ARGS[1] = "https://www." + compareString;
    } else {
        SELECTION_ARGS = new String[4];
        SELECTION_ARGS[0] = compareString;
        SELECTION_ARGS[1] = "www." + compareString;
        SELECTION_ARGS[2] = "http://" + compareString;
        SELECTION_ARGS[3] = "http://" + SELECTION_ARGS[1];
    }
    Cursor cursor = cr.query(Browser.BOOKMARKS_URI, Browser.HISTORY_PROJECTION, secure ? WHERE_CLAUSE_SECURE : WHERE_CLAUSE, SELECTION_ARGS, null);
    ContentValues map = new ContentValues();
    if (cursor.moveToFirst() && cursor.getInt(Browser.HISTORY_PROJECTION_BOOKMARK_INDEX) == 0) {
        // This means we have been to this site but not bookmarked
        // it, so convert the history item to a bookmark
        map.put(Browser.BookmarkColumns.CREATED, creationTime);
        map.put(Browser.BookmarkColumns.TITLE, name);
        map.put(Browser.BookmarkColumns.BOOKMARK, 1);
        // map.put(Browser.BookmarkColumns.THUMBNAIL, bitmapToBytes(thumbnail));
        cr.update(Browser.BOOKMARKS_URI, map, "_id = " + cursor.getInt(0), null);
    } else {
        int count = cursor.getCount();
        boolean matchedTitle = false;
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            // One or more bookmarks already exist for this site.
            // Check the names of each
            cursor.moveToPosition(i);
            if (cursor.getString(Browser.HISTORY_PROJECTION_TITLE_INDEX).equals(name)) {
                // The old bookmark has the same name.
                // Update its creation time.
                map.put(Browser.BookmarkColumns.CREATED, creationTime);
                cr.update(Browser.BOOKMARKS_URI, map, "_id = " + cursor.getInt(0), null);
                matchedTitle = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (!matchedTitle) {
            // Adding a bookmark for a site the user has visited,
            // or a new bookmark (with a different name) for a site
            // the user has visited
            map.put(Browser.BookmarkColumns.TITLE, name);
            map.put(Browser.BookmarkColumns.URL, url);
            map.put(Browser.BookmarkColumns.CREATED, creationTime);
            map.put(Browser.BookmarkColumns.BOOKMARK, 1);
            map.put(Browser.BookmarkColumns.DATE, 0);
            // map.put(Browser.BookmarkColumns.THUMBNAIL, bitmapToBytes(thumbnail));
            int visits = 0;
            if (count > 0) {
                // The user has already bookmarked, and possibly
                // visited this site. However, they are creating
                // a new bookmark with the same url but a different
                // name. The new bookmark should have the same
                // number of visits as the already created bookmark.
                visits = cursor.getInt(Browser.HISTORY_PROJECTION_VISITS_INDEX);
            }
            // Bookmark starts with 3 extra visits so that it will
            // bubble up in the most visited and goto search box
            map.put(Browser.BookmarkColumns.VISITS, visits + 3);
            cr.insert(Browser.BOOKMARKS_URI, map);
        }
    }
    if (retainIcon) {
        WebIconDatabase.getInstance().retainIconForPageUrl(url);
    }
    cursor.close();

}
```

You can see the OS code [here](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android-apps/4.2.2_r1/com/android/browser/AddBookmarkPage.java?av=f)